# Как не давать программе завершиться Golang

Tags: golang

Как не давать программе завершиться даже если у нее будут критические или фатальные ошибки. Какая функция или метод отвечают за это? Код:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "net/http"
import "runtime"

func main() {

    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)

    go func(host string) {
        req, err := http.Get(host)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Err")
        } 
        fmt.Println(req.Body)
        defer req.Body.Close()
    } ("http://golang.org")

    var s string
    fmt.Scanln(&s)

}
```

Тут может быть куча ошибок таких как:

> Get https://golang.org/: dial tcp 172.217.16.49:443: connectex: A
>   connection attempt failed because  the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected  host has failed to respond.

Из-за разорванного соединения между сервером и клиентом и т.д.
После одной из ошибок нужно вновь попытаться соединиться с сервером. 
Как это можно сделать? Читал документацию и там было что-то сказано про метод recovery, но я не совсем понял с моим то плохим английским.

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, ошибка возникает вот здесь:

```
req, err := http.Get(host)
if err != nil {
```

В первом приближении задача будет выглядеть так - если `err != nil` то надо подождать какое-то время и попробовать повторить запрос.

Я в данном случае использую вот такую вспомогательную функцию:

```
func retry(attempts int, sleep time.Duration, f func() error) (err error) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        err = f()
        if err == nil {
            return
        }

        if i >= (attempts - 1) {
            break
        }

        time.Sleep(sleep)

        log.Println("retrying after error:", err)
    }
    return fmt.Errorf("after %d attempts, last error: %s", attempts, err)
}
```

На вход она принимает количество попыток, которые надо сделать, задержку между попытками и, собственно, функцию, которую надо выполнить. Это удобно, так как подобный код не надо повторять в нескольких местах программы.

Ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var req ...

retry(10, 1 * time.Minute, func() (err error) {
  req, err = http.Get(host)
  return
})
```

Comment: Переделал вы мне подсказали но все равно падает при `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x40 pc=0x602f32]`

Comment: Надо весь код смотреть. Ошибка другая - не о разрыве соединения, а о неправильной работе с указателями.

Comment: Я понял что ошибка возникает из-за того что req ссылается на указатель с nil то есть req.Body не несет в себе информации что == nil; Код: https://pastebin.com/RhuNA8u6 . Только вот почему?

Comment: В моем коде req специально объявлена за пределами функции retry. Там же (после функции retry) с этим значением и надо работать, когда результат уже получен.

Comment: На всякий случай поясню. Назначение функции retry - выполнять кусочек кода, пока он не будет без ошибок выполнен. Этот кусочек кода мы передаем в функцию в виде третьего параметра. Хорошо бы, чтобы этот кусочек кода был минимальным. В идеале только та строка, что может завершиться с ошибкой (что я и привел в примере).  И уж точно в этой функции не стоит обращаться к значению req (как это делаете вы), так как в этой функции может быть ситуация, что запрос еще успешно не отработал и вы так ничего и не получили. Ну как минимум - добавить проверку на ошибку.

Comment: сейчас изменил код и вроде бы все работает, программу не выбивает, panic не возникает ведет log - 2018/01/06 17:21:05 retrying after error: Get http://golang.org: dial tcp 216.58.209.81:80: connectex: Only one usage of
 each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. Но думаю все-же где-то есть нерпавильный фрагмент кода так-как задержка не выполняется. Можете пожалуйста подсказать где я может что-то неправильно сделал. https://pastebin.com/eJVun8wq

Comment: Что именно не работает ? Я не понимаю значение фразы "задержка не выполняется"

Comment: задержка в 1 минуту после того как произошла ошибка

Comment: Как вы это определяете ? У вас создается 100 000 горутин, которые параллельно выполняют эту функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```
req, err := http.Get(host)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    // повторяем запрос
    req, err = http.Get(host)
}
```

И так далее. Хоть в бесконечный цикл такое заверните.